# Should the core module import the shared module in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Following several advices on how to structure an angular application, I end up with this file organization :

```
- app
    - core
        - header
        - sidenav
        core.module.ts
    - shared
        - material
            custom-material.module.ts
        shared.module.ts
    - features
    app.module.ts
```

- I have a *core module* and a *shared module*
- The *core module* exports global components such as *HeaderComponent* or *SidenavComponent*
- The *shared module* exports a *CustomMaterial* submodule (I heard it was the way to do things)
- The *CustomMaterial* submodule exports the different material components I need
- The *app module* only imports the *core module* (since shared module should only be imported by elements that need it)
- The modules in `features/` are lazy loaded

But now, my problem is : my header component needs some material components.

**Should I import my shared module into my core module** or into my app module ? But it seems like an anti-pattern to me.

Comment: This question is pretty old, and the only answer given doesn't really seem to answer the question. I came here looking for an answer to this as well. From what I have found, it seems that it is okay for the `CoreModule` to import the `SharedModule`, but should not export it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is to create a shared.module.ts inside whom you should import all the material modules you want to use everywhere(MatInputModule, MatButtonModule,etc..) and export all these imported modules (which makes you able to import them in another module, calling this shared module).

The small thing to do after that, is just to import this shared module containing all the material modules, inside your header module and footer module for example (if you need MatInputModule of course)

Hope i have been clear

Have a nice day !

Comment: But this way the shared module is imported into the header module, that is imported into the core module, that is imported into the app module... and I heard it was not a good practice to import the shared module into the app module, implying the shared module to be global, am I wrong ? Have a nice day too :)

Comment: Not if you are doing lazy loading ;). The shared Module will be loaded inside HeaderModule for example, but not inside the app.module because it won't be imported to the app.module at run time ;)

Comment: Even if my HeaderModule is inside my CoreModule ? I mean, there is no routing inside CoreModule and HeaderModule is not lazy loaded, Can you explain why it won't be imported at run time ?

Answer (score 0):

Importing needed modules should be ideal unless you are not
facing recursive import conflicts between two or more modules.